# KineticJS 4.7 remove getElement method

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

In the past I use kineticJS 4.6

When I want to add an attr to html element, I've just have to call

```
$(layer.getCanvas().getElement()).attr('data-iwant_to_access_from_JS', 'value')
```

I've update to kineticJS > 4.7, and I've message "... has no method getElement()

When I check the source code of KineticJS, I find this method was remove.

How can I add attr to the CANVAS attr element ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution if I replace with

```
$(layer.getCanvas()._canvas).attr('data-iwant_to_access_from_JS', 'value')
```

But it's not very elegant, and I don't understand why they remove this method

Comment: It's intentionally not very elegant.  You're grabbing a reference to 1 of the 2 **private internal** Kinetic canvases that support a Kinetic Layer.

Comment: sure, but how can I do without it ?

Comment: You can't get the underlying canvas more easily.  KineticJS normally reserves these canvases for itself and they are not normally available to directly code against.  As you've discovered, you can do it...just do it at your own risk.